# Opencv; How to free IplImage*?

Tags: c++, opencv, memory, free, allocation

I am trying to get a hang of OpenCV. At the moment I am trying to subtract two frames from each other and display the result. I have found example code which will do that just fine.
My problem is that I am getting a memory allocation error.
Well, nothing to special about that, because I am feeding the program with HD video.
So my question is how do I release the allocated memory of an IplImage*?
The Mat type has something like Mat.release().
IplImage does not have that, nor does free(IplImage) work.

Here is my code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui_c.h>


using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    std::string videofilename;

    std::cout << "Please specify the video name (make sure it is in the same folder\nas the application!):" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> videofilename;
    std::cout << "The name you provided: " << videofilename << std::endl;

    VideoCapture video(videofilename);

    if(!video.isOpened())
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open video file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "Number of frames: " << video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Duration: "<< static_cast<int>(video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))/(30*60) << "min " << static_cast<int>((video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)))%(30*60)/30 << "sek" << std::endl;

    // Close it before opening for playing
    video.release();

    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromAVI(videofilename.c_str()); 
    IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    IplImage* currframe = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
    IplImage* destframe = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);


    if ( !capture ) 
    {  
        std::cout << "Could not open video file" << std::endl;
        return -1; 
    }

    cvNamedWindow("dest", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while(1)
    {
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

        if(!frame)
        {
            printf("Capture Finished\n");
            break;
        }

        currframe = cvCloneImage(frame);    // copy frame to current
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);        // grab frame

        if(!frame)
        {
            printf("Capture Finished\n");
            break;
        }

        cvSub(frame, currframe, destframe);    // subtraction between the last frame to cur
        cvShowImage("dest", destframe);
        //cvReleaseImage(currframe); // doesn't work
        //free(currframe); // doesnt work either
        //delete(currframe); //again, no luck
        cvWaitKey(30);
    }

cvDestroyWindow("dest");
cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: please *avoid* IplImages, cv* functions, the whole outdated c-api. you already opened a VideoCapture successfully, now go and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can free `IplImage` using `cvReleaseImage`. It takes address of a pointer to an `IplImage`, i.e. `IplImage**` as argument, so you have to do this:

```
cvReleaseImage(&currframe);
```

instead of `cvReleaseImage(currframe);`.

But keep in mind, the image returned by `cvQueryFrame`, (`frame` in your case) is a special case and it should not be released or modified. Also, you don't have to preallocate `currFrame` if you are going to initialize it using `cvCloneImage` eventually.

The final code would look like this:

```
int main()
{
std::string videofilename;

std::cout << "Please specify the video name (make sure it is in the same folder\nas the application!):" << std::endl;
std::cin >> videofilename;
std::cout << "The name you provided: " << videofilename << std::endl;

VideoCapture video(videofilename);

if(!video.isOpened())
{
    std::cout << "Could not open video file" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

std::cout << "Number of frames: " << video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Duration: "<< static_cast<int>(video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))/(30*60) << "min " << static_cast<int>((video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)))%(30*60)/30 << "sek" << std::endl;

// Close it before opening for playing
video.release();

CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromAVI(videofilename.c_str()); 
IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
IplImage* currframe;
IplImage* destframe = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);


if ( !capture ) 
{  
    std::cout << "Could not open video file" << std::endl;
    return -1; 
}

cvNamedWindow("dest", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

while(1)
{
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

    if(!frame)
    {
        printf("Capture Finished\n");
        break;
    }

    currframe = cvCloneImage(frame);    // copy frame to current
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);        // grab frame

    if(!frame)
    {
        printf("Capture Finished\n");
        break;
    }

    cvSub(frame, currframe, destframe);    // subtraction between the last frame to cur
    cvShowImage("dest", destframe);
    cvWaitKey(30);
    cvReleaseImage(&currframe);
}

cvDestroyWindow("dest");
cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm! I just forgot about the damn "&" :(. Anyway, the first comment to my question suggested to use an the VideoCapture class instead of the cv stuff. Would the be many benefits if I change the code again? Thx

Comment: @user2175762... Well, if you use the C++ API instead of C API, the code would be less and easier to manage. Also, you wouldn't have to worry about memory management as it would be automatically handled by the classes.

Comment: @user2175762... You may consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @sgarizvi what if I am querying frame from a video in                                 while (frame = cvQueryFrame(cap))

Comment: Wouldn't I have a memory leak

Comment: @JumabekAlikhanov... No, there won't be a memory leak. OpenCV uses an internal buffer to store the frame being acquired from `CvCapture`. So when we query a new frame, the same memory buffer is used rather than new memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cvReleaseImage()`. For example, if you want to release `IplImage* frame`, use `cvReleaseImage(&frame)`.

For `Mat`, you don't need to release it explicitly. It will release automatically when out of its code block.

---

**Edit**: take a look at [here](http://cuby5566.pixnet.net/blog/post/45059668-%5B-opencv-%5D-iplimage-release) on more details about `cvReleaseImage()`, which addresses on some wrong releasing situations.